# Uploading ipa file to firebase and getting error "server error. Write EPIPE"

Tags: firebase, ipa

I'm trying to upload ipa file to firebase and getting the following (token is specified in FIREBASE_TOKEN env)

```
% firebase appdistribution:distribute build/app.ipa --app 1:XXXXXXX:ios:XXXXXXXX --groups app-team --release-notes-file ReleaseNotes.txt

i  uploading binary...

Error: failed to upload release. Server Error. write EPIPE
```

MacOS 11.4, firebase 9.23.1

Any ideas why so?